Make a new dataframe of duplicated rows by column names from boolean columns?
I have a boolean table of four columns in a dataframe with some other fields e.g.
  A B C D X
  ---------
1 T T F T 0.1
2 F T F F 0.2
3 F F T T 0.3

There are more than one field X but let's just use X for this example.
How can I make a new table of duplicated rows by column names?
  Type  X
  -------
1 A   0.1
1 B   0.1
1 D   0.1
2 B   0.2
3 C   0.3
3 D   0.3


Lookup tidyr::pivot_longer.

@Edward can you explain? I think just doing that doesn't give me what I need.

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, cols=A:D, names_to="Type") |>
   filter(value) |>
   select(-value)


# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id     X Type 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1   0.1 A    
2     1   0.1 B    
3     1   0.1 D    
4     2   0.2 B    
5     3   0.3 C    
6     3   0.3 D


Data:
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), A = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), B = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE), C = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), D = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
), X = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


This might be fast
x = LETTERS[1:4]
data.frame(
  id = (j <- df[x] * df[["id"]])[j != 0], 
  Type = matrix(rep(x, each = nrow(df)), ncol = length(x))[j != 0],
  X = (i <- df[x] * df[["X"]])[i != 0]
  ) |> sort_by(~id) # cosmetics 

giving
  id Type   X
1  1    A 0.1
2  1    B 0.1
5  1    D 0.1
3  2    B 0.2
4  3    C 0.3
6  3    D 0.3

